# Postgresql How to update catalog statistics

Tags: postgresql, catalog, table-statistics

how to update the catalog statistics in postgresql to check the query performance.I searched on google but I did not find anything on internet regarding update catalog statistics

Comment: Run [ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It will show the statistics but how to update the catalog statistics?

Comment: Read the info in the link, `ANALYZE` updates the catalog statistics. You can use it on one table(or columns within a table) or all tables and table like objects in the database.

Comment: Perhaps you should define what you mean by "catalog statistics". Are you talking about optimizer statistics on a user table or about optimizer statistics on a catalog table?